# Return ViewModel instead of Model

Tags: c#, linq, viewmodel

The following method returns a `IEnumerable` `MODEL` called `PROF`.

Instead of using the model, I want to use a `viewModel` which contains the same fields as the `Model PROF`. How can i make changes to the following function to return my `VIEWMODEL`(which is called `MyProfViewModel` ) instead of the `model` (which is called `PROF` ).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var cp= db.PROF.Include(c => c.ACCOUNTS);

    return View(await cp.ToListAsync());
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyProfViewModel
    {


        public int myprofID { get; set; }

        public string myprofDes{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class PROF
    {


        public int ID{ get; set; }

        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to "map" the model to viewmodel and return that...?

Comment: Can you tell me how it's done. I am a newbie.

Comment: If the properties were actually named *the same* (and not just similar), then you could use a AutoMapper and the [`ProjectToListAsync<MyProfViewModel>()` extension method](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/07/08/entity-framework-extensions-for-automapper/).

Comment: @CharlesMager Can you give me more details on `AutoMapper`. You mean if I have named my attributes with the same name in both the model and viewmodel ?

Comment: @CharlesMager that's an advice which can be considered good, however I would just like to add that to OP and future visitors that you need to weigh pros/cons of introducing another layer of abstraction/tool just for mapping easy tasks like this. JoelHarkes answer greatly shows an easier and probably faster way than say Auto-/or any other mapper tools.

Comment: @Illep if you want to know more about AutoMapper, then go to the [website](http://automapper.org/) or use google to find plenty of blogs, tutorials, questions on here etc. Also note *kayess* advice above. AutoMapper can be a great time saver if you find you're writing a lot of  brain-dead mapping code, but probably shouldn't be introduced for one simple use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a select statement which maps one type to another:

```
db.PROF.Include(c => c.ACCOUNTS)
       .Select(x=> new MyProfViewModel(){myprofID = x.ID, ...});
```

Depending on if this select statement is supported by your ORM layer (Entity Framework?), I would do it before, or after `.ListAsync();`

Pros of before: could lead to better optimized SQL queries.

Answer (score 5):

Joel's answer is pretty much it. But since you mentioned you are starting I will provide a more deltailed answer to make more clear how to use.

First you define a conversion, in this case I put it in the ViewModel, but you can put it somewhere else that would make more sense in your project:

```
public class MyProfViewModel
{
    public int myprofID { get; set; }

    public string myprofDes { get; set; }

    public static MyProfViewModel FromModel(PROF model)
    {
        var viewModel = new MyProfViewModel()
        {
            myprofID = model.ID,
            myprofDes = model.DESCRIPTION
        };
        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

Then you just apply the conversion before returning:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var cp = PROF.Include(c => c.ACCOUNTS);
        var models = await cp.ToListAsync();

        var viewModels = models.Select(MyProfViewModel.FromModel);

        return View(viewModels);
    }
```

By the way, you can make the tranformation to models as well by adding this to your ViewModel class:

```
    public PROF ToModel()
    {
        return new PROF()
        {
            ID = this.myprofID,
            DESCRIPTION = this.myprofDes
        };
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup. Thank you. Helps a lot.